# Guitar chords application with a catalogue of fingering charts and alternate chord symbols

Tags: gratis, web-apps, music

The title pretty much says it all.

I am looking for a web application to display fingering charts for chords on the guitar that

- has all the chords (including advanced jazz chords) with

  - alternative chord symbols
  - alternative fingerings
- [optionally] can do a reverse lookup

of course it should

- be freely accessible
- have a clean modern gui.

It should be intended to serve as an interactive encyclopedia.

Comment: The way you've asked this question makes it very tough to answer. Mainly because of the subjective nature of your requirements. It may be helpful to give the use case for which you'd like to use the tool?

Answer (score 1):

The one that I found is a Flash application called [chordbook](http://www.chordbook.com/guitarchords.php).

It provides diagrams for

- chord types shown below together with
- their inversions (for alternative positions).

However, it does **not** fit the requirements in terms of

- alternative chord symbols / names and
- reverse chord finding didn't work for `Em9 (X7577X)`.

[image: chordbook]

Answer (score 1):

Chord.Rocks is a free website that works on any browser/device.

It will show alternative chord names and symbols and display alternate finger positions. Also, you can enter any alternate tuning or add a capo.

http://chord.rocks/guitar/chords

It has a reverse chord lookup feature. Also with alt tuning and capo options.

http://chord.rocks/guitar/identify-chord

Comment: What is your affiliation with that website? Please disclose.

Answer (score 0):

[Vex Fretboard](http://my.vexflow.com/) is a web application that displays guitar tab notation.

If you are so inclined, the [code for it](https://github.com/0xfe/fretboard).

I have not explored it much, so I am not sure if it fits all of your requirements.

It is fairly new, so there isn't much content posted on it at the moment, but something like this should give you a good idea of what it is about.

[Sample article](http://my.vexflow.com/articles/2)

Comment: Thanks, this software looks quite interesting, but it is very different from a chord diagram encyclopedia. It seems to be a pure notation software, that renders vextab (another notation, syntactically related to ChordPro) to music sheets / tablatures. Please correct me, if I've overlooked something.

Comment: It can produce chord diagrams (now?) http://vexflow.com/vexchords/